# Popup is triggered multiple times with short time interval

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I wanted to make an input field to react to invalid inputs dynamically in such a way that a popup (with window.alert) will be displayed to inform the players of the invalid input. However, after I close the popup, the very same popup will be displayed twice with very short time interval between. The input can be changed after this though.

How can I solve it? Would there be a way to make sure that the popup is not displayed again for a couple of second?

Relevant code:

```
$(':input').bind('keypress keydown keyup change',function(){
  var weight = parseFloat(String($(':input[name='.concat(n,']')).val()).replace(',', '.'));

  if (weight > 100 || weight < 0){
      window.alert("Bitte eine Nummer zwischen 0 und 100 eingeben!");
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding 4 events to do the same thing, so you should get 4 alerts:

All 4 event fires because you press the key, and release the key, and since the element looses focus when you do the alert, also the change-event is fired.

- [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) (Deprecated) fired when a key that produces a character value is pressed down
- [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event)  is fired when a key is pressed.
- [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event) is fired when a key is released.
- [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) is fired when value is committed by the user.

You forgot the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)-event to be complete...

Use the change-event, to only run your code when the value is committed by the user.